# Xcode - preprocessor directive check which SDK is being used

Tags: cocoa, xcode, preprocessor

I am making some changes to an existing library which uses the "[addTimeInterval:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDate/addTimeInterval%3a)" function which was deprecated in OS X v10.6. I would like to supress the warning using a preprocessor directive to check which SDK version the current build is using. Something like this:

```
NSDate *newDate= nil;

#if OS X v10.6 (or newer)
newDate= [someOtherDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
#else
newDate= [someOtherDate addTimeInterval:60];
#endif
```

Is this at all possible using Xcode 4?

Comment: If you do that, you'll be changing the behavior once at build time. If that code is built once and run everywhere, it will invoke the 10.6 code on older platforms.

Answer (score 4):

How about [`+[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000188-dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow_) that's been around since 10.0?

---

Maybe instead of doing a compile-time check, you could do a runtime check:

```
if ([[NSDate class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(dateByAddingTimeInterval:)]) {
  newDate = [someOtherDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
} else {
  newDate = [someOtherDate addTimeInterval:60];
}
```

Comment: That was just an example piece of code, I dont really need to add time to "now". Ideally this library would work on all (or most) versions of OS X and iOS.

Answer (score 3):

```
#if (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_6)
    newDate = [someOtherDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];
#else
    newDate = [someOtherDate addTimeInterval:60];
#endif
```

But it won't work with 10.5 if you build it with 10.6 SDK. need a runtime check as @Dave said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the exact same technique I described in [CLLocation getDistanceFrom: vs distanceFromLocation:](http://0xced.blogspot.com/2010/09/cllocation-getdistancefrom-vs.html)

Juste replace `CLLocation` with `NSDate`, `getDistanceFrom:` with `addTimeInterval:` and `distanceFromLocation:` with `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` in the instructions and you'll be able to always use `dateByAddingTimeInterval:` no matter what SDK you are using and no matter what OS version you are running.